# Save taxonomy Term id with a specific Termid in drupal8

Tags: php, drupal-8

Iam trying to migrate taxonomy from drupal7 to drupal8 programatically.where term id will be different for a vocabulary while migrating to new site.how can i migrate taxonomy term with old termid?

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to able to export the SQL query from drupal 7 taxonomy table and import in D8 taxonomy table. Once you export and import the data using SQL query you may be able to change the term ID manually directly to the database using any of the Mysql Client tool.